# How to replicate ini folding in udf

Tags: notepad++

I tried to replicate this ini folding syntax highlighting

[image]

I only put [ ] in middle at udf settings.

my udf code result

[image]

look at the red line, still not the same

Answer (score -1):

Ok after taking a close look, this looks like an issue with notepad++ if you just copied and pasted.

I code in notepad++ all the time, and sometimes I notice that the syntax highlighting doesn't show up properly, sometimes rewriting by hand works because there was a whitespace or unwanted hidden character somewhere in there that happened on the copy and paste.

If they look exactly the same to you, then often the only reliable solution is to rewrite it.

Sometimes copying into notepad to try to strip unwanted characters works as well.

Sometimes when I want to be completely sure I stripped out all unwanted characters, I will paste it into the browser URL bar and then cut that because the URL bar usually strips unwanted characters. Then I paste that into notepad++ again, only thing is you need to re-insert the line breaks because the URL bar will also strip the line breaks.

Sometimes even the URL bar isn't enough so I will paste the code into notepad, then cut and paste it into the URL bar, and if still no go I'll look up some textarea on a website somewhere which can't read anything but text and also put it into there.

If all else fails, then re-typing the whole line will work, although this can be tedious so sometime paste and cut from a source which strips all unwanted characters will do the trick.